# dapper C# поиск в базе данный всех полей со значением null

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Работаю с dapper недавно.

Есть модель

```
    [Table("test", Schema = "myShema")]
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Key][Column("id")] public short Id { get; set; }
        [Column("parent_id")] public short? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

ParentId - в бд частично заполнена значениями null

и соответственно метод работающий с бд (осуществляет поиск по ней)

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<IMyModel>> FindAsync(short? id = null, short? parentId = null)
        {
            var res = await _xxx.SqlConnection.QueryAsync<MyModel>(
                $@"SELECT   
                    mymodel.id AS {nameof(MyModel.Id)},
                    mymodel.parent_id AS {nameof(MyModel.ParentId)}
                FROM 
                    myShema.mymodel as mymodel
                WHERE
                    (@Id IS NULL OR @Id = mymodel.id)
                    AND (@ParentId IS NULL OR @ParentId = mymodel.parent_id)
                    ",
                 new
                {
                    Id = id,
                    ParentId = parentId,

                 });

            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IMyModel>>(res);
        }
```

Задача в том, что нужно выводить только записи где parent_id равен null.... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать... например с добавлением нового параметра...

В Бд 50 значений.
В коде вызываем

```
 var parents = xxx.FindAsync();
```

в parents прилетело 50 значений.

```
 var parents = xxx.FindAsync(parentId: 4);
```

в parents все значения у которых в бд 4 в данном столбце.

необходимо

```
var parents = xxx.FindAsync(parentId: false)
```

в parents все значения у которых в бд null в данном столбце.

Comment: `нужно выводить только записи где parent_id равен null` : `AND (@ParentId IS NULL OR @ParentId = mymodel.parent_id)` ===> `AND (mymodel.parent_id IS NULL)`

Comment: @tym32167 Мне необходимо оставить существующий фильтор...и добавить с null

Comment: `AND (mymodel.parent_id IS NULL OR @ParentId = mymodel.parent_id)` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Если все фильтры не заданы, отваливаются часть значений... Есть 50 записей...если фильтры не заданы выводи все 50, если задано найти по parentId выводим например 20 по заданому условию...а если нужно вывести все c null...не удается передать его в качестве параметра

Comment: Я не понимаю вашу последнюю фразу. Попробуйте переформулировать, а ещё лучше приведите данные на входе\выходе\и фильтры, чтобы понять вашу задачу было легче. Сделайте это в вопросе, вы можете его редактировать.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил описание

Comment: Сделайте отдельный метод для получения всех записей `var parents = xxx.FindAllAsync();` и не мучайтесь

Comment: @tym32167 увы, задача состоит в том, что бы расширить функционал данной функции; все работает кроме последнего

Comment: вы же понимаете, что вот этот вызов `var parents = xxx.FindAsync(parentId: null);` ничем не отличается от этого `var parents = xxx.FindAsync();`?

Comment: @tym32167 понимаю, но необходимо, что то примерное придумать...

Comment: Если новые функции вам создавать нельзя, то вы можете добавить 2 дополнительных параметра, типа bool searchById, bool searchByParentId, это будет работать, но само по себе решение так себе.

Comment: @tym32167 Вам будет несложно показать как хотя бы 1 параметр в релизовать во 2 случае....мне примерно так и нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<IMyModel>> FindAsync(short? id = null, short? parentId = null, bool? hasParentId = null)
        {
            var res = await _xxx.SqlConnection.QueryAsync<MyModel>(
                $@"SELECT   
                    mymodel.id AS {nameof(MyModel.Id)},
                    mymodel.parent_id AS {nameof(MyModel.ParentId)}
                FROM 
                    myShema.mymodel as mymodel
                WHERE
                    (@Id IS NULL OR @Id = mymodel.id)
                    AND (@ParentId IS NULL OR @ParentId = mymodel.parent_id)
                    AND (case
                         WHEN (@HasParentId IS NOT NULL and @HasParentId is true) Then mymodel.parent_id is not null
                         WHEN (@HasParentId IS NOT NULL and @HasParentId is false) Then mymodel.parent_id is null
                         WHEN (@HasParentId IS NULL) Then @HasParentId is null
                        END)
                    ",
                 new
                {
                    Id = id,
                    ParentId = parentId,
                    HasParentId = hasParentId
                 });

            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IMyModel>>(res);
        }
```

Comment: Можно закрывать.

Answer (score 1):

Проверять код мне некогда и негде, но идея должна быть понятна

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IMyModel>> FindAsync(
                        bool filterById = false, 
                        bool filterByParentId = false, 
                        short? id = null, 
                        short? parentId = null)
{

    var query = $@"SELECT   
                    mymodel.id AS {nameof(MyModel.Id)},
                    mymodel.parent_id AS {nameof(MyModel.ParentId)}
                FROM 
                    myShema.mymodel as mymodel";
    if (filterById || filterByParentId) query += " WHERE ";

    if (filterById) query += " (@Id IS NULL OR @Id = mymodel.id) ";

    if (filterById && filterByParentId) query += " AND ";

    if (filterByParentId) query += " (@ParentId IS NULL OR @ParentId = mymodel.parent_id) ";

    var res = await _xxx.SqlConnection.QueryAsync<MyModel>(
        query,
         new
         {
             Id = id,
             ParentId = parentId,

         });

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IMyModel>>(res);
}
```